# Group by join 3 tables in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have 3 tables `Order`, `Product`, `ProductCategory`.

I want to join these three tables on `productId` in `Order` table and `productId` in the `Product` table. Also `ProductCategory` in `Product` table and `ProductCategoryID` in `ProdoductCategory` table.

Now I want to `Group by` Order table based on the product category id and the result which I needed is the sum of the amount of each product category.

How can I join these three tables in EF Core 6 and select the result data according to which I need?

Comment: In EF Core we don't deal with tables, columns and joins, but classes, properties and navigations (a.k.a. model). If you need help with EF Core, please include the relevant part of the model in the question (rather than explanation of tables, columns and joins). Also what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You should use .include for joining three table
Second use .GroupBy for Grouping table according to joined filed between table
Third use .select According to your needed field for resulted dataset.
your Code maybe like this:

```
GroupBy(x => x.Product.InsuranceCompanyId)
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    g.First().Product.InsuranceCompanyId,
                    Share = g.Sum(c => c.Price * 1.09),
                    OrderDate = date
                })
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I hope this sample will work for you